# DeclarativeFieldsMetaclass object argument after ** must be a mapping, not int

Tags: python, django

I am trying to pass kwargs to my forms.py file, when the form is loaded I get an error saying my car_id is not defined on my forms.py file. I know this is because of the below line of code but I do not know how to fix it.

form = SelectCarModelForm()

forms.py

```
def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
    self.car_id = kwargs.pop('car_id', None)
    super(SelectCarModelForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
    self.fields['car_model'] = forms.ModelChoiceField(
        empty_label = "Select a Model",
        queryset = CarModel.objects.filter(model=car_id),
        widget = Select(attrs={'class': 'span12 small-margin-top small-margin-bottom'}),
        required=True
    )
```

view

```
    if request.method == "POST":

        form = SelectCarModelForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            model = form.cleaned_data['car_model']




            # Go to the next form in the process.
            return redirect('view_car')


    # Initial form
    else:

        form = SelectCarModelForm()

    return render(
        request,
        template_name = 'cars/forms/view_car_models.html',
        dictionary = {
            'form':form,

        }
    )
```

Answer (score 0):

You either do this:

```
# pass a `car_id` value when instantiating the form
form = SelectCarModelForm(car_id=<some_value>)
```

and if that's not feasible, maybe this:

```
def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
    self.car_id = kwargs.pop('car_id', None)
    super(SelectCarModelForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
    if self.car_id is not None:
        self.fields['car_model'] = forms.ModelChoiceField(
            empty_label = "Select a Model",
            queryset = CarModel.objects.filter(model=car_id),
            widget = Select(attrs={'class': 'span12 small-margin-top small-margin-bottom'}),
            required=True
        )
    else:
        self.fields['car_model'] = forms.ModelChoiceField(
            empty_label = "Select a Model",
            queryset = CarModel.objects.filter(model=<SOME-OTHER-CRITERIA),
            widget = Select(attrs={'class': 'span12 small-margin-top small-margin-bottom'}),
            required=True
        )
```